# search a string inside a element and then put it in a conditional statement

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

for example i have a input, anchor tags, divident or any element that a value could be possible. how to search inside a element like to see if there is a 
 attribute inside of it or any value as i desire and then put it in a conditional statement like if and elseif statement and check if the selector has a 
 inside and if there is then alert yes else alert no or in php, echo yes if there a 
 inside, else echo yes.

I tried this. assume i have a textarea

```
var isFound = $("#apostform textarea").val().search("<br>");
alert ('there is');
```

question: is the alert box is still be executed even if we found no 
 inside of the specified text area?

I need this to be done in javascript, jquery, and in php. thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DOM objects have properties, to search all properties for particular value you can use a for..in loop:

```
for (var prop in element) {

  if ( element[prop] == 'some value' ) {

    // do stuff

  } else {

    // do other stuff

  }
}
```

or if you know the property you're after and just want to see if it has a truthy value:

```
if (element.property) {
  // do stuff
}
```

Answer (score 0):

with jquery:

```
if ($("element[your-attribute]").length) {
    //element has the attribute, do-something
}
```

Comment: not working, could you post something like 'jsfiddle' please?

Answer (score 0):

here are the code snippets you'll need

```
//retrieve elements having a special attribute
//for example input tags who are radio buttons
$('input[type=radio]');
```

you can also use the .attr() method to retrieve nad check an attribute of an element

```
if($myElement.attr('my_attribute').equals('desiredValue')){ /* do this   */}
```

to alert use following :

```
window.alert('my message here');
```